# Can't receive broadcasts for PACKAGE intents

Tags: android

I am trying to register a Broadcast Receiver to receive broadcast events for the package events. Following is the code and my receiver in the manifest file. The log statment never happens, but I can clearly see the same broadcast firing for "HomeLoaders" (the Launcher) debug statements. What am I missing?

```
public class IntentListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("INTENT LISTNER:", intent.getAction());
    }
}

<receiver android:name="IntentListener" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="package"></data>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"></action>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"></action>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: the error can be in IntentListener instead of com.android.samples.app.IntentListener ?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that these `Intent`s cannot be received by components registered in the manifest, but only by receivers registered in Java via `registerReceiver()`.

Comment: Yea im pretty sure thats the case, out of curiosity why is this the case? I don't see any security implications of this?

Comment: As I commented on another SO question a day or so ago, Android does not necessarily want to start up a new component all of the time. The one case I knew of was for battery events (e.g., ACTION_BATTERY_LOW). It looks like SCREEN_OFF (and maybe SCREEN_ON) are others. If you think of it, and you get it working with registerReceiver(), chime back on this issue. I think I need to cover this topic in a blog post and/or book section, and unfortunately the list of no-manifest-receiver Intents is undocumented.

Comment: I would like to see where this is documented.  I have inspected the source and the only check against these protected broadcasts is so a non system process cannot initiate a broadcast.  I have also seen other packages in the source register for this intent through the manifest only.

Answer (score 0):

This is my manifest, without

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

My app detects only the [Android Market](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play) app install, but does not remove. Now it receives also the non-Android Market app broadcasts.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".SomeActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.som.pakage.PackageInstallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

These three intents namely,

```
Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED
Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED
Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED
```

when broadcasted by the system, have

```
Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY_BEFORE_BOOT
```

flag added so that only the registered receivers will receive the broadcasts and no broadcast receiver components will be launched. Refer Intent and PackageManagerService class of source for further details.