# BroadcastReceiver does not work, no notification

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have tried to do a simple app (or, more specifically a Receiver):
When the user presses the "Camera button" or "Dealer button" - the app raises a notification.

There isn't an ERROR, but the app doesn't work.

I have tried to add permission but it still doesn't work.

**MyDownloadBroadcastReceiver.java:**

```
package elyahsiv.raisenotificationwhendownloadfile;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
public class MyDownloadBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("NOTES:", intent.getAction());
        if (intent.getAction() == "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")
            showNotification(context);
        else if (intent.getAction() == "android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON")
            showNotification(context);
    }
    private void showNotification(Context context) {
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Hello World!");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="elyahsiv.raisenotificationwhendownloadfile">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".MyDownloadBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your error log.

Comment: There isn't error. Just, Although I clicked on the buttons - raise no notification...

Comment: atleast post the reciever class properly

Comment: I'm sorry. Somehow the signature escaped me ...

Comment: And how are you calling `receiver` ?

Comment: Do you mean "MyDownloadBroadcastReceiver"?

Comment: Yes. `MyDownloadBroadcastReceiver`

Comment: I did not fully understand the question. When I specify its name in the XML file it does not call the match class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions have to be declared just before application tag.
You got to have android.permission.CAMERA and maybe more.
In intent filter you got to have

```
<data android:scheme="package" />
```

Consider splitting receiver in three different ones.
Also

> Due to a broadcast behavior change since Android 3.1, your app must be started before it can receive the app installation/removal intents. See kabuko's answer [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515310/broadcast-receiver-for-package-added-not-working-from-android-3-1-onwards).

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888768/package-added-broadcastreceiver-doesnt-work).

Try to register your receiver  when activity or service is created.
Also you should consider the following:

> Apps that target Android 8.0 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest.

For example:

```
MyDownloadBroadcastReceiver receiver = new MyDownloadBroadcastReceiver(); 
IntentFilter receiverFilterCameraButton = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON");
registerReceiver( receiver, receiverFilterCameraButton );
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried everything and for some reason, still does not work .. Do you have another idea or a way to find out what went wrong?