# Android receiver cannot always get broadcast correctly

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, package

I have a package added receiver in my Android application, and has been distributed for a couple months.

Recently I found that not all the PACKAGE_ADDED broadcasts can be received by my receiver.

looked up a while, someone said that if your app had been killed by users or system, then you will no longer get broadcasts.

My questions are:

1. Is that true?
      confirmed, if you terminate your app from Settings->Applications --> force stop
      then your application wont receive any broadcast.
2. How can I prevent this happening, or is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

1.Yes that is true.

2.Take a look at [`WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) that will wake up when it receives an Intent. Then make sure you spawn eg. an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) so it will process your work in the background.

Take a look at CommonsWare's [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) for implementation example.

Comment: I tried WakefulBroadcastReceiver, but it dosen`t work when I terminate my application manually, I cannot receive any PACKAGE_ADDED broadcast anymore

Comment: and I assume you've registered your receiver in the Manifest and not in your code? If not make sure to register your receiver in the Manifest.

Comment: I have registered it in Manifest. still  dosen`t work.

Comment: do you have the `<data android:scheme="package" />`in the intent filter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888768/package-added-broadcastreceiver-doesnt-work

Comment: also it seems like it might not work; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593022/cant-receive-broadcasts-for-package-intents/1596466#1596466. If this is true then I would take advantage of the alarm manager and register the receiver at certain intervals.

Comment: Thx for ur suggestions. I would take those in consideration.